# How adding the onclick function into a href in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

How could I adding the onclick function: `onclick="this.classList.toggle('toggle');` into a href in the WordPress.Or using the javascript function add to the a href?

Source code image: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdjPf.png)

Any plugin or solution can help, thanks?

Comment: where is this `a` coming from?

Comment: thats a wordpress theme source code page, I only see it by using inspect, but cannot find source code page in backend.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use the following jquery code to add the onclick to a(anchor) tag.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#collapsible-widget-2 a").attr('onclick',"this.classList.toggle('toggle')");
    });
```

or if you want onclick function inside a href then you can use following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#collapsible-widget-2 a").attr('href',"onclick='this.classList.toggle('toggle')'");
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work that I added the script to my WordPress footer.

Comment: Please check whether you have added jquery cdn or not? I have tested this code in my codepen you can take a look https://codepen.io/Nirvana11/pen/MGMOBO